# Python - Pandas won't import because numpy version is incompatible. But numpy won't update

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, jupyter

I had to re-install anaconda and Jupyter now I can't import pandas in Jupyter notebook. It says to upgrade numpy to 1.7.0. Have done this, but problem still persists

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     21 
     22 # numpy compat
---> 23 from pandas.compat.numpy import *
     24 
     25 try:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
     22                       'your numpy version is {0}.\n'
     23                       'Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.7.0 to use '
---> 24                       'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
     25 
     26 

ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.7.0
your numpy version is 1.6.2.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.7.0 to use this pandas version
```

Comment: Strange because Anaconda includes the correct dependencies for both. Did you update running `conda update`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have your path setup correctly. You are not linking to the anaconda distribution. Make sure you have your `.bash_profile` file is correctly setup--assuming you're on a bash shell. Add this line in your `.bash_profile` if not there:

````
# added by Anaconda3 4.3.0 installer
# need to change path to Anaconda directory if not in your home directory
# this is setup for Python3.6 in my home directory
export PATH="/Users/home_dir/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"```
````

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but no change. As I commented above I think something is wrong with the install of anaconda

Comment: Problem resolved. jupyter was importing an older version of numpy which I tracked down and deleted. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndyFyers can you please share how you deleted the numpy that jupyter was tracking? I am facing the same problem.